# Button setting true or false "auth" at random

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I'm trying to set the "auth" to true when I click to loggin, but sometimes he does true, and other times he set to false, so when I refresh the home after the login, he sendme to login again. Someone can see why?

To more details, this is React.js, consuming a Spring api and I need to get the JWT Token (bearer), and login as true

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Logo from '../Logo'
import './Styles.css'
import axios from 'axios';

import { AuthProvider, Context } from '../../Context/AuthContext'
import api from '../../Services/api';
import { createContext } from 'react';

export default function FormLogin() {

    
    const { token, setToken } = useContext(Context)
    const {auth, setAuth} = useContext(Context);
    const [form, setForm] = useState({ usuario: '', senha: '' })
    const history = useHistory()

    async function handleLogin() {

        //console.log(auth);
        try {
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('nome', form.usuario);
        params.append('senha', form.senha);
        const retorno = await api.post('login', params);
        console.log(retorno.data.tokenacesso)
        const authtru = await setAuth(true)
        

        const settok = await setToken({
            tokenAcesso: retorno.data.tokenacesso,
            tokenRefresh: retorno.data.tokenrefresh
           
        })
        //This need to be deleted of course
        console.log("");
        console.log(token.tokenAcesso);
        const locauth = await localStorage.setItem("auth", auth)
        const loctok = await localStorage.setItem("tokenA", token.tokenAcesso)
        history.push("/")
       

        //localStorage
        } catch (error) {
            const tk = await setToken({
                tokenAcesso: "",
                tokenRefresh: ""
            })
           const auti = await setAuth(false)
           const lcssi = await localStorage.setItem("auth", auth)
            
           
        }
       

    }

    function changeForm(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setForm({ ...form, [name]: value })
        console.log(form);
    }

    const validarLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            handleLogin()
        } catch (erro) {
            alert("dados invalidos!")
        }

    }


    return (
        <div className='login-main-container'>
            <Logo />
            <h2 >LOGIN</h2>
            <Form className="login-input" onSubmit={validarLogin}>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">

                    <Form.Label >Usuário</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="name"
                        name="usuario"
                        value={form.usuario}
                        placeholder="Entre com seu usuário"
                        onChange={changeForm}
                    />
                    <Form.Text
                        className="text-muted"

                    >
                    </Form.Text>

                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">

                    <Form.Label >Senha</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        name="senha"
                        value={form.senha}
                        placeholder="Entre com sua Senha"
                        onChange={changeForm}
                    />
                    <Form.Text
                        className="text-muted"

                    >
                    </Form.Text>

                </Form.Group>

                <Button variant="outline-primary" size="lg" type="submit" md="auto">
                    ENTRAR
                </Button>
            </Form>

        </div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what happens:

- you click on the submit button
- some asynchronous stuff happens which takes a while, like `api.post('login', params)`
- when the asynchronous stuff is finished (after all the `await`s) then `auth` in the localStorage is set to `true`

If you reload the page after submit but before the asynchronous stuff is finished, then the `auth` in the localStorage never got set to `true`.

The different results happen if you reload earlier or later, or if the api response comes earlier or later.

You can observe the "Network" tab in the browser dev-tools to confirm if the request is finished or not.

E.g. you will get `auth: true`:

```
--[submit]--[api-request]------------------------------,---[reload]
                     \                                /
                      \---[response]---[auth:true]---/
```

...you will get `auth: false`:

```
--[submit]--[api-request]-----------[reload]
                   \
                    \-----(no response yet...)-------X
```